# Coordinative ellipsis with not and unparellel structure

Tags: ellipses, coordinating-conjunctions

> I worked and did not play.
>
> I worked and not played. ?

For some reason, when the ellipsis is used after the simple past form of the verb with no "to be" used before it, it just sounds weird to me. Is there something wrong with it, or is it just that it is not idiomatical? Or am I the one who's wrong?

> I had to control myself and not cry in front of her.

I always thought that second part has been used independently and not connected to the "had to" part, for I thought there should be additional "to" like this

I had to control myself and had to not cry.

Or at least this: I had to control myself and to not cry in front of her. (It doesn't sound very idiomatic... is it acceptable?)

Is the "to" deleted? If it is, why is that?

And also, when I was trying to find the answer for this question, it was clear that everybody was asserting only the parallel form should be allowed for the ellipsis after the coordinating conjunction. For example:

> Sarah is [a CEO] and [proud of her job]. - NP + AP
>
> Is Jim [conservative] and [a closet Republican]? - A + NP
>
> He is a crazy man and may drink a lot. -NP+V

These (only the three sentences directly above it) are from Wikipedia, and not regarded as being incorrect. But looking up at the other websites, I find that they say that it is wrong, even though many people, including me, use it this way. They say that it should be parallel like this:

> Sarah is [a CEO] and [a person proud of her job]. - NP + NP

Is it supposed to be always parallel?

Comment: The correct (and rather old-fashioned; maybe even obsolete) word order would be *"I worked and played not"*. Consider the biblical *"they toil not, neither do they spin."*

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with it. Negative verbs like _not play_ require _Do_-Support, even when their subject has been omitted. You can't say **I not played*, so you can't say **I worked and not played*.

Comment: @JohnLawler Right. So if there'd been an emphatic *DO* before *work*, it would have been grammatical: "I *did* work and not play"

Comment: Yes, that would work. Though both clauses would be interpreted as emphatic, they would both have infinitives following _do_. The negative infinitive form of a verb is _not_, followed by the infinitive form of the verb. Defective verbs like modal auxiliaries and _beware_, which don't have infinitives, don't have negative infinitives either.

Comment: @JohnLawler : "I worked, not played" is perfectly correct and clear. No *do* needed. ... Personally, I prefer: "I worked and knot-played." ;)

Comment: Can you cite which websites claim the citations by Wikipedia are incorrect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For these to be correct you must be able to attach the subject to both of the phrases surrounding the coordinating conjunction individually, as you stated. There is no reason for a sentence to not be correct if it follows this rule.

> - I [worked] and [did not play].
> - I [worked] and [not played].

The first sentence is correct because you can split it into *I worked* and *I did not play* whereas splitting the second sentence gets you *I not played* which is ungrammatical, therefore the original sentence is ungrammatical.

> - I had to [control myself] and [not cry in front of her].
> - I had [to control myself] and [to not cry in front of her].

Both of these are technically correct, however the first is much more fluid. The second sentence is grammatical but can take on a slightly different meaning than the first sentence. Here, not crying in front of her is implicitly a separate event from controlling yourself because the *to* after *and* "resets" the function of the coordinating conjunction; the *and* implies a relationship between the two phrases, but inserting *to* breaks this.

> - Sarah is [a CEO] and [proud of her job].
> - Sarah is [a CEO] and [a person proud of her job].
> - Sarah [is a CEO] and [is proud of her job].

These are all grammatical based on my first point. I have added a third version because this is one of the more common ways this sentence would be used. Many would say the first is too short, the second is too long, but the third is just right. Past the rule I stated, there isn't a definitive way to pick the truly correct version here. It's all user preference because they're all grammatical.

---

A little bit on parallel and unparallel structure:
Both structures are correct and can be used interchangeably. In my explanations above, I was stressing parallel structure since it is the better way to go. However, unparallel structure still works. Here is an example:

> I bought a new refrigerator, dish washer, and the oven will be delivered tomorrow.

This is unparallel because the sentence can be split into two parts, *I bought a new refrigerator* and *I bought a new dish washer*, but the third part doesn't follow the *I bought a new* pattern. The third part grammatically fits but doesn't keep the pattern. This structure is used quite often, but it isn't the more correct way to write.

Comment: "Here, not crying in front of her is implicitly a separate event from controlling yourself because the to after and "resets" the function of the coordinating conjunction; the and implies a relationship between the two phrases, but inserting to breaks this. " This is quiet hard to understand. Does it mean that the "to" starts whole new event that is separate from the first event, controlling myself, therefore destroying the relationship between those two sentences? Then how can it be grammatical?

Comment: +1 to Adam.
@sooeithdk: There are two events:
1. to control yourself and 2. to not cry in front of her.
The first line indicates that you have to control yourself from crying.
The second sentence - using "to" after "and" takes a different meaning because it does not implicitly imply that you are controlling yourself from crying. It indicates two different actions-  controlling yourself from something and to not cry in front of her.

Comment: Is using "to" once again basically same as using "had to" again? EX: I had to control myself and to not cry in front of her = I had to control myself and had to not cry in front of her.

Comment: @sooeithdk Yes, that's actually a better way to explain it. You hit the nail on the head. By using words that appear at the beginning (outside the two phrases), you reset the idea.

Comment: Why is it OK "to" use only to then? Had to is used like a one word here, right?

Comment: _Had_ is taken out of both phrases and put at the beginning, so it is technically part of both. If we took _to_ out also, the conjunction would function better.

Comment: Taken out of both? Isn't it taken out of only the second phrase after the conjunction?

Comment: The idea is that anything at the beginning can be applied to both phrases. So _I had to control myself_ and _I had to not cry_ both have _I had_. But looking further, they also share the _to_. We can take the _to_ out of both and place it at the beginning.

Comment: I agree on everything you've said @Adam except for the following:

Sarah is [a CEO] and [proud of her job].

Though gramatically correct I think this sentence is SEMANTICALLY unparallel. It's just putting apples and monkeys together by means of a conjunction. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: @M-b That's true, but to be fair, I never mentioned parallel or unparallel structures.

Comment: Yes, it was one of the questions I was asking about. Is there a strict rule that says it always has to be parallel? I see tons of unparallel structure everywhere, even in the newspaper. Is it just a silly rule for immature writers, or is it something official like subject verb agreement?

Comment: There is no rule stating unparallel structure is wrong. Unparallel structures are simply _less correct_ that parallel structures. I'll add a little bit to my answer on this. Sorry for not doing that in the first place.