# Using "of" after a coordinating conjuction

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

How should I say this?

> 1. The color of the chair and the table ...
> 2. The color of the chair and of the table ...

Why should that option be used (apart from being the correct one)?

Comment: See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/274697/121024) for a good explanation of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first example suggests that the chair and table both have (or are expected to have) the same colour, whereas the second example maintains greater separation between the two objects, allowing for them to differ in colour.
Of course, this is just semantics, and there is no grammatical reason against using either. But if you're interested in real-life usage rather than theory, my points stand.